# Routing static folder name in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, routes, cakephp-2.0

I tried this from my browser:

```
http://example.com/contact
```

But then I get "**Controller class ContactController could not be found**" error

It doesn't exist because "contact" is a folder name that isn't a part of CakePHP application. It has 2 php files inside, but they works standalone. They are not CakePHP app files.

I tried this:

```
Router::redirect('/contact/*', 'http://example.com/contact/',
    array('status' => 302));
```

But I got this error from browser
"**This webpage has a redirect loop**"

How can I make a redirection so I don't get this error?

Comment: Can you put the contact folder within webroot?

Comment: What Dave said! If you put the contact folder in /app/webroot Cake will know where to find it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible adding a mod_rewrite rule.

Suppose your app path is:

```
/var/www/
/var/www/app
/var/www/app/webroot
```

Add your folder "contact" to

```
/var/www/contact
```

Find the CakePHP .htaccess at

```
/var/www/.htaccess
```

This are the original contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Add the rule bellow after the "RewriteEngine on" line

```
RewriteRule  ^contact -               [L]
```

It will look like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule  ^contact -           [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Solving this issue from the **.htaccess** is better way than the **routes.php**. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good lord...!! Community had completely corrupted my brain with "do it the CakePHP way" cr@p.. I had completely forgotten that I can directly play with `.htaccess` instead of doing it in `routes.php`. Thanks man! Cheers